# How to change hyperlink tooltip based on condition

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to change the colour and tooltip of a hyperlink based on a condition.
Below is the code:

```
<Hyperlink x:Name="HyperLink"
            TextDecorations="UnderLine"
            FontSize="12"
            FontWeight="SemiBold" 
            Command="{Binding Path=DummyCommand}" >

    <Run Text="{Binding Path=HyperLinkText}"/>

    <Hyperlink.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Has Access"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasPermission}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="No Access"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Hyperlink.Style>

</Hyperlink>
```

When HasPermission becomes false, hyperlink colour changes to gray.***But I couldn't see the tooltip for the same.***

Note: **HasPermission=false when DummyCommand.CanExecute(null) is false.

      DummyCommand is a command which is bound to Command Property of hyperlink.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. This may help.
 I used `TooltipServive.ShowOnDisabled = true` before `DataTrigger`. It Works fine

```
<Hyperlink.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Has Access"/>
        Added line---->
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasPermission}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="No Access"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Hyperlink.Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a DataTrigger for the true case without setting the properties in style?

```
<Hyperlink.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasPermission}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Has Access"/>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasPermission}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="No Access"/>
                </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Hyperlink.Style>
```

Comment: I got the answer. If I set TooltipService.ShowOnDisabled property = true before data trigger, it works.